# Is there a significance to a matrix having an eigenvector equal to a column vector within a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider matrix $A$:

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -2\\
3 & -3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

After little computing, we find the eigenvectors (and their corresponding eigenvalues) to be equal to

$E_{\lambda=0}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix},\
E_{\lambda=-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

What, if any, is the significance of $\lambda$'s -1 eigenvector? I ask this because it is the same as the first column in the original matrix $A$ and I am curious to see if their is a specific set of parameters for this to occur and/or if this is significant in any way.

Comment: This does make it easier to compute the successive powers of $A$.  Outside that, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to interpret the matrix as representing a "dynamical system" where the state after time $t$ had elapsed was given by $A^{t}x_0$ ($x_0$ the initial position), the eigenvector is where all states would eventually tend to. The reason your eigenvector is a column of the matrix is because *all* columns of the matrix are parallel - in general if we let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}c_0\textbf{x}&c_1\textbf{x}&\dots &c_n\textbf{x}\end{bmatrix}$$ ($\textbf{x}$ a vector) then for any input $y$ we will get $$A\textbf{y}=c\textbf{x}$$ for some constant $c$. Clearly then, $\textbf{x}$ will be an eigenvector of $A$ (and perhaps one of its columns!) because it will get sent to something parallel to itself.

Note however that there is nothing *specifically significant* per se about the eigenvector actually *being* a column. You could just as well have said that the eigenvector was $c\times\text{eigenvector}$ for any non-zero scalar and then it would not have been an actual column in the matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I was using the New Age Suburban Deconstructivist spelling... :) thnx

Comment: hehe that feeling when you just know something's not right...